# I'm Unable to get html to display everything in this github zip

Tags: html, jquery, css, json, angularjs

I'm just trying to open the index.html and it does not display the navigation or images that should be on the page. https://github.com/LawlietBlack/Persona-4-Golden-Guide

If this question needs to be asked some place else let me know. I just cant figure this out and in the past I have gotten great help with python here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run it from an actual web server instead of just opening the html file. If you are on a mac, you can simply open terminal, `cd` into the folder and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` then open your browser and go to `localhost:8000` and it should load fine. Be sure to quit the web server when you are done.

Comment: No mac but very good at python. I'll try this now. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know enough about android to really help you there... but if it were me I would just put the files on a host (like netlify or github pages) and access via browser. If you're doing android development I'm sure there's some sort of web-frame component that is basically an in-app browser. Also - make sure you check with the author for permissions/licensing in case you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks and I'm crediting the creator. I have sent him an email but no reply thus far.